# Will "cpsie" arm instruction case TLB miss?

Tags: linux, arm, kernel, tlb, perf

When I profiled my program, I found that "_raw_spin_unlock_irq" system call causes a lot of iTLB miss on the ARM Cortex A15 Board. After I carefully checked the assembly code, I found that "cpsie" instruction may be one of the reasons. Thus, I programmed a short code to verify my assumption.

Following is my code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
void compute()
{
     int i = 100000000;
     do {
         asm volatile(
                     "cpsie i"
                     :
                     :
                     : "memory", "cc"
         i--;
     } while (i > 0);
}
int main()
{
     compute();
     return 0;
}
```

Then I used perf tool to check the iTLB miss, it reports:

89172 dTLB-load-misses

5694  dTLB-store-misses

43248 iTLB-load-misses

After removed the "cpsie i" instruction, the result is:

23453 dTLB-load-misses

1453 dTLB-store-misses

12035 iTLB-load-misses

The result shows that the "cpsie i" increased 4 times iTLB misses. I annotated the binary code using perf report, 69.5% iTLB misses happened adjacent after "cpsie i" instructions.

```
       │    void compute()                                                                                       
       │    {                                                                                                     
       │      push   {r7}                                                                                         
       │      sub    sp, #12                                                                                      
       │      add    r7,                                                                                          
       │            int i = 100000000;                                                                            
       │      mov.w  r3, #57600      ; 0xe100                                                                     
       │      movt   r3, #1525       ; 0x5f5                                                                      
       │      str    r3, [r7, #4]                                                                                 
       │            do {                                                                                          
       │                    asm volatile(                                                                         
 13.93 │      cpsie  i                                                                                            
       │                            "cpsie i"                                                                     
       │                            :                                                                             
       │                            :                                                                             
       │                            :"memory", "cc");                                                             
       │                    i--;                                                                                  
 69.26 │      ldr    r3, [r7, #4]                                                                                 
       │      subs   r3, #1                                                                                       
       │      str    r3, [r7, #4]                                                                                 
       │            }while(i > 0);                                                                                
 16.80 │      ldr    r3, [r7, #4]                                                                                 
       │      cmp    r3,                                                                                          
       │      bgt.n  8400 <compute+0x10>                                                                          
       │    }                                                                                                     
       │      add.w  r7, r7, #12                                                                                  
       │      mov    sp,                                                                                          
       │      pop    {r7}                                                                                         
       │      bx     lr
```

I am confused that why a lot of iTLB misses happened after "cpsie  i" instruction? Is there any way can I prevent it? Thanks!

Comment: I do not think cpsie is responsible for that, but the "memory" keyword....

Comment: are you using cpsie from user mode?

Comment: or I should say user land?

Comment: Actually, I just tried the "cpsie" instruction. In "_raw_spin_unlock_irq" system call, the perf also reported 99.6% of iTLB misses happened after "cpsie i".

Comment: See: [ARM CPS doc](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/Cihfdbhd.html) to give *CPS is only allowed in privileged modes, and has no effect in User mode.*  It is possibly doing an *undefined instruction* in user mode; try with a `cpsid f` and see if the same happens.  For the `spin_lock` case, of course this makes sense.  You disable interrupts; when you re-able them, something pends and an interrupt handler causes a table walk and new *iTLB* entries.

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried "cpsid f" and "cpsie f", it shows the same happens. I will try to lock one iTLB including "spin_lock" codes. Is there any other solution?